# How Can I solve the facebook redirect uri error?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am gonna create a facebook login with PHP and MySQL.
So, I built a simple form and add the facebook login button.
After then, I crate an app on facebook developer console.
But I am getting such error when click the Facebook Login Button.
Here is the error.

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

[image]

I look forward to hearing from you about the solution.
Please let me know if you have any question.
Looking to your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook added settings for the `Facebook Login` product. To add a valid redirect URL, you have to go to the left menu, below `Products`, there should be something named `Facebook Login`.

```
Facebook Login > Settings > Valid OAuth redirect URIs
```

Update it and click on `Save Changes` then try again.

### Screenshot of left menu

[image]

### Screenshot of Client OAuth Settings

[image]

Comment: I forgot about that. Sorry. :) Keep in touch

Comment: @D.Sean Thanks! :)

Comment: You are welcome. I will contact you if I have another issue. Thanks for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Ah, are you free now? I have a job. Let's discuss about that via chat. Invite me on chat. Looking to your reply